# Get proportion of missing values per Country

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

[image]

I would like to find the proportion of missing values of my features on each country and on all years to select the countries.

I tried this:

```
df[indicators].isna().mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

but it gives me the proportion of missing values for each indicator only...

i would like this output :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape and then aggregate `mean` of missing values:

```
df1 = (df.melt(id_vars='Country Name', value_vars=indicators)
         .set_index('Country Name')['value'].isna()
         .groupby('Country Name')
         .mean()
         .reset_index(name='Prop'))
```

Or reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Country Name')[indicators]
         .stack(dropna=False)
         .isna()
         .groupby('Country Name')
         .mean()
         .reset_index(name='Prop')
        )
```

Or use custom function:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Country Name')[indicators]
         .apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.isna().to_numpy(), axis=None))
         .reset_index(name='Prop'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the result is all NaN

Comment: @Giordano - So `print(df[indicators].isna().sum(axis=1))` return `NaN`s ?

Comment: It is counting the number of NaN for each rows, it's working ! but i would like to display only one the countries and not the years, assuming that the proportion is already calculate for all years.

Comment: @Giordano - I think Iknow problem. Need `.groupby(['Country Name'], as_index=False)` instead `.groupby(['Country Name', 'Year'], as_index=False)`

Comment: for exemple i have 19 times Afghanistan and 5 indicators, so 19 x 5 = 95 values. I have only 7 NaN, so the proportion should be p = 7/95 = 0.07 and i have 0.36 now

Comment: @Giordano - per country there is multiple same years? Not per country is unique year?

Comment: i have only unique years per country

Comment: @Giordano - hmmm, so why aggregate by county and years? then it has no sense. I think need aggregate by countries, because duplicated. Answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you that's it, i need now to add each columns together to add all indicators values

Comment: @Giordano - Can you add expected output from data sample in question? Because not undertand what need.

Comment: question edited with desired output

Comment: @Giordano - what is `indicators` ?

Comment: all the 5 columns : Internet users (per 100 people), GDP per capita (current US$) Population, ages 15-24, total Population of the official age for upper secondary education, both sexes (number) Population of the official age for tertiary education, both sexes (number)

Comment: @Giordano - and how is count `Albania` if no in data sample in question? Also `0.07` is count 7/25 ? But is is not `0.07` in data in question

Comment: sorry i made it by hand because i have all the countries in the world, and i have calculate the proportion by hand with df.head()

Comment: @Giordano - answer was edited, now working well?

Comment: still have 0.36 of proportion instead of 0.07 i don't get it, i need to check that again

Comment: @Giordano - how many values is per `Afganistan` ? And how many `NaN`s ?

Comment: 95 values and 7 NaN

Comment: @Giordano - Solution was edited.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !